# Appending key, values to a nested dict in for loop in python

Tags: python

I have four values derived from each for loop. I am expecting something store like this (four key/values derived from each for loop should be appended).

Expected result:

```
dict = {'1': {'aa': {'bb': 'cc'}
             {'xx': {'yy': 'zz'}, 
        '2': {'dd': {'ee': 'ff'},
             {'gg': {'hh': 'ii'}}
```

But with my approach, I can only store last/ latest key-value pairs in the dictionary (key-value pairs are not getting appended instead they are being overwritten with latest key/values).

My approach:

```
d = dict()
d [id][name1] = dict()
d [id][name1][name2] = [name3]
```

My result:

```
d = {'1': {'xx': {'yy': 'zz'}},
     '2': {'gg': {'hh': 'ii'}}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @mikey I added "my approach" in the question.

Comment: Your expected result is not valid. You cannot have two separate values for the same key in a `dict`. If you want multiple values per key you need to put them in some sort of a container (`tuple`, `list`, `set`...)

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your expected result? I think it misses some `,` .

Comment: Dictionaries associate each key *with a single value*.

Comment: @vmonteco - he's missing a lot more than the obvious comma...